# Will the files load multiple times in HTML if we load same in an Iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am making a Website and for faster loading, I want to optimize that. So, I want that less HTTP requests occur.

Suppose in an HTML file, we are loading some files (style, script and images).

```
<style rel="text/stylesheet" href="/style.css"></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js"></script>
<img src="/image.png"></img>

<iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>
```

Now, In above code, we loaded an iframe. This is the code for the Iframe.

```
<style rel="text/stylesheet" href="/style.css"></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js"></script>
<img src="/image.png"></img>
```

As we can see that the style.css, script.js and image.png are loading in both iframe and main HTML page.

So I want to know that, Will these files load multiple times or it will load from cache(When loading in the iframe)?

What are the ways to optimize this code?

Answer (score 0):

The files will be loaded from browser cache as long as their absolute URLs remain the same.

Comment: Will there be any expiry date or time??

Comment: each browser handles this differently, mostly by limiting the size the cache may occupy on disk; but you can (try(!!)) to hint at time-to-live via header data https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control